# How to remove a property from the ignored list in Jackson Databind?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data, jackson-databind

I have a situation where a Spring Boot module has been updated to pay attention to ignored properties return from `POJOPropertiesCollector` in Jackson Databind. The issue is when you use `@JsonProperty(access = READ_ONLY)` Jackson adds that to the list of ignored properties, and it removes it from being a sortable field for `Pageable` objects.

I'm currently looking for a way of removing a property from the `_ignoredPropertyNames` that Jackson Databind collects in `POJOPropertiesCollector`, whilst maintaining read only access to the property. I've tried `@JsonIgnore(value = false)`, different permutations of `@JsonProperty()`, restricting it on setters and getters but all of them end up with an ignored property.

Additional info:
Jackson Databind 2.8.8
Spring Boot 1.5.11-RELEASE

Basic Example:

```
public interface AuditingFieldMixin {
  @JsonProperty(access = READ_ONLY)
  @JsonIgnore(value = false)
  public abstract DateTime getCreatedDate();
}
```

Comment: `JsonProperty` and `@JsonIgnore` added at the same time for the same field does not look like a good idea. What was an original problem that you wanted to use them at the same time? There is also a concept of [split property](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) when getters and setters have one from these annotation.

Comment: The more I look at the issue the less I think I can work around with Jackson, I suspect I need to tackle it at Springs level instead